# Is there a way to untangle SQL log by connection in Sequel

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

I'm using the Sequel gem which works great. However I'm trying to debug a multithreading bug so I activated the log (at the Sequel level : .i.e using a Logger when creating the connection to the database). My problem is , all the SQL logs coming from the different connections are tangled in the log file and there is no know which query correspond to which connection. Having a connection id or something added to the log would be really useful.

Is there a way to do so or an alternative solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If there's nothing built-in, try monkey patching or changing the logger, or the call to it, so it prepends each log line with the thread's ID.

The relevant file in Sequel would be:

https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/lib/sequel/database/logging.rb

Based on it, chances are you could subclass Logger and throw that in to make it work.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html

If the Logger docs and its code is anything to go by, you can probably do what you want by overriding the `add()` method, e.g.:

```
def add(severity, message = nil, progname = nil, &block)
  thread_msg = "thread: #{Thread.current.object_id}"
  progname ||= @progname
  if message.nil?
    if block_given?
      message = yield
    else
      message = progname
      progname = @progname
    end
  end
  message = "#{thread_msg}\n#{message}"
  super(severity, message, progname, &block)
end
```

Comment: That's a good idea, even though I was hoping from a built-in solution. However, this solution allows to untangle by thread but not by connection. I'm mean, I'm trying to debug a problem which appears when 2 different threads are using the same connexion. I'll have a look at sequel logging.rb file